# TypeError: Cannot read property 'permissions' of null discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was trying to make an anti-link bad word thing and it doesn't understand roles I suppose.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
if(message.member.permissions.has('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return
                    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'permissions' of null
```

And this is my code:

```js
    const fs = require('fs')
    module.exports = (client) => {
    client.on('message', async message => {
      if(message.member.permissions.has('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return
        let warnings = {}
        let warnCount = 3
        let warnCount2 = 5
        let warnCount3 = 7
        warnings = fs.readFileSync('./db.json', 'utf8');
        warnings = JSON.parse(warnings)
          if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes('fuk')) {
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send(`${message.author.username} was warned for posting links`)
            if(!warnings[message.author.id]) warnings[message.author.id] = {
              warnings: 0
            }
            warnings[message.author.id].warnings += 1
            console.log(`${message.author.tag} was warned in ${message.guild.name}. Warnings: ${warnings[message.author.id].warnings}`)
            if(warnings[message.author.id].warnings == warnCount){
             let muterole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Muted')
             if(!muterole) return message.channel.send('cant mute because theres no roles such as "Muted"')
             await message.guildMember.roles.add(muterole)
             await message.channel.send(`${message.author.tag} was muted for 1m. Reason: Unknown Link`)
             setTimeout(async() => {
               await message.member.roles.remove(muterole)
               await message.channel.send(`${message.author.tag} was unmuted`)
             }, 60000)
           }
           if(warnings[message.author.id].warnings == warnCount2){
             let muterole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Muted')
             if(!muterole) return message.channel.send('cant mute because theres no roles such as "Muted"')
             await message.guildMember.roles.add(muterole)
             await message.channel.send(`${message.author.tag} was muted for 1h. Reason: Unknown Link`)
             setTimeout(async() => {
               await message.member.roles.remove(muterole)
               await message.channel.send(`${message.author.tag} was unmuted`)
             }, 3600000)
           }
          fs.writeFileSync('./db.json', JSON.stringify(warnings));
        })
    }
```

Comment: Have you enabled all necessary intents?

Comment: Also, you should use `messageCreate` instead of `message` as event in v13

Comment: Hey @Toasty umm i have all intents i'd need and about messageCreate i'm not sure but its not necessary

Comment: @Lokry you have to change the event to `messageCreate` if you want your Bot to work properly

Comment: @Lokry It is neccessary

Comment: `message.member` returns null when the message was sent in a DM, have you tried using the command in a server

Comment: @Elitezen it doesn't send to DM

Comment: Can you show us how you enabled the intents?

Comment: And did you change the event name already?

Comment: let client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] })
yes i did but it doesn't even react to the message

Comment: @Lokry I'm referring to the initial command message that emits the event

Comment: You mean like 
`const antiBadwords = require('./commands/antiBadwords')
antiBadwords(client)
const antiLinks = require('./commands/antiLinks')
antiLinks(client, Discord)
const antiSpam = require('./commands/antiSpam')
antiSpam(client, map, Discord)`

Comment: Try running your command inside a server

Comment: This is a weird issue because `message.member` should only be `null` when the message is a DM, yet the OP does not appear to have the channel partial enabled and therefore cannot actually receive DMs. Perhaps the issue is that the event handler received a system message with no member, such as one of the default "x user joined the server" Discord messages. Just avoid this by adding `if (!message.member) return;` at the top of the handler.

Answer (score 0):

if you are v14 using like this will works
you can read this guide it will help you with your issue
[https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#roles-as-bot-permissions]

```
const { PermissionsBitField } = require('discord.js');

if (member.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.KickMembers)) {
    console.log('This member can kick');
}

if (member.permissions.has([PermissionsBitField.Flags.KickMembers, PermissionsBitField.Flags.BanMembers])) {
    console.log('This member can kick and ban');
}

if (member.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.KickMembers, false)) {
    console.log('This member can kick without allowing admin to override');
}
```

and if you v13 i found this from this I prefer to update discordjs to v14 [https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/understanding/roles.md]

```
let perms = message.member.permissions;

// Check if a member has specific permission on the guild!
let has_kick = perms.has("KICK_MEMBERS");
```

> I tried my best to help if there was something wrong or I am sorry
> this is my first post answer